# XSLT Transformation: Transform the message or sent an empty message depending on a condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to process a message and depending on a condition I want to apply a transformation, or to send an empty message (just ) depending on that condition, but I am not able to generate the empty message.

I was expecting to not send anything not putting content inside the when element, , however it sends all the message (without the transformation), how can I specify not to send a message if the condition inside the when clause is true?

This is the xml I need to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A1>
    <B1 d2p1:type="UntrackedItem"
          xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <C1>SI</C1>
    </B1>
</A1>
```

This is the xslt that I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
                indent="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <!--This will add the attribute Origin to the main element-->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="A1/B1/C1[text() = 'SI']">        
                <!--Empty message-->
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--Applies the transformation-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="A1">
        <xsl:element name="A1">
            <xsl:attribute name="Orig">
                <xsl:value-of select="22"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- This will copy all the nodes that do not match the above -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the expected outputs are the following:

1- If the condition is accomplished:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

2- If the condition is not accomplished:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A1 Orig="22">
      <B1 xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       d2p1:type="UntrackedItem">
            <C1>SI</C1>
      </B1>
</A1>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant XML, otherwise we can't judge the XSLT, other than telling that using `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` in a template with `match="/"` seems meaningless as far as `@*` is concerned.

Comment: Well, we could also say that for doing something when a condition is true and nothing otherwise it would be sufficient to use `xsl:if`. Or that you should not be using `xsl: element` when the name of the element is known in advance. But really we need to see a [mcve] in order to answer your question.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen , I am newbie to xslt that's probably the cause of what you are seeing, I have added the code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k added the sample, thanks!!

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9e9